# How to change the file name of an uploaded file in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Is it possible to change the file name of an uploaded file in django? I searched, but couldn't find any answer.

My requirement is whenever a file is uploaded its file name should be changed in the following format.

```
format = userid + transaction_uuid + file_extension
```

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 64, accepted):

How are you uploading the file?
I assume with the `FileField`.

The documentation for [FileField.upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) says that the `upload_to` field,

> may also be a callable, such as a
> function, which will be called to
> obtain the upload path, including the
> filename. This callable must be able
> to accept two arguments, and return a
> Unix-style path (with forward slashes)
> to be passed along to the storage
> system. The two arguments that will be
> passed are:

> "**instance**": An instance of
> the model where the `FileField` is
> defined. More specifically, this is
> the particular instance where the
> current file is being attached.
>
> "**filename**":The filename that was
> originally given to the file. This may
> or may not be taken into account when
> determining the final destination
> path.

So it looks like you just need to make a function to do your name handling and return the path.

```
def update_filename(instance, filename):
    path = "upload/path/"
    format = instance.userid + instance.transaction_uuid + instance.file_extension
    return os.path.join(path, format)
```

Comment: excepting if the file exists; does the storage butcher your creation to get a unique name?

Comment: For others coming to the answer (like me) please note that the path cannot start with a / otherwise django will through an error due to a "Suspicious Operation" so you use @monkut 's example `path = "/upload/path/"` should be `path = "upload/path/"`

Comment: be careful that if you create your custom validation function in a form like `def clean_my_audio_file_field(self):` then **the result of this function will override** whatever you do in the `upload_to= parameter`

Comment: What if you want the file name to include the value from a drop down menu? How can you make that value available to `models.py`?

Comment: @SoftwareEnthusiastic Can you let me know  this function def update_file_name() where this was written in views.py?

Comment: What if you need instance.id to generate the filename?

Comment: include it in the returned string, `return f'{instance.id}/{filename}'`

Answer (score 13):

You need to have a `FileField` with the `upload_to` that calls to a callback, see [1]

Your callback should call a wrapper method which gets an instance as one of the params and filename as the other. [2]

Change it the way you like and return the new path [3]

### 1. LOGIC

```
FileField(..., upload_to=method_call(params),....)
```

### 2. define method

```
def method_call(params):
    return u'abc'
```

### 3. Wrapper:

```
def wrapper(instance, filename):
    return method
```

this is the rapper method that you need for getting the instance.

```
def wrapper(instance, filename):
... Your logic
...
return wrapper
```

### Complete Code

```
def path_and_rename(path, prefix):
    def wrapper(instance, filename):
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
        project = "pid_%s" % (instance.project.id,)
        # get filename
        if instance.pk:
            complaint_id = "cid_%s" % (instance.pk,)
            filename = '{}.{}.{}.{}'.format(prefix, project, complaint_id, ext)
        else:
            # set filename as random string
            random_id = "rid_%s" % (uuid4().hex,)
            filename = '{}.{}.{}.{}'.format(prefix, project, random_id, ext)
            # return the whole path to the file
        return os.path.join(path, filename)

    return wrapper
```

### Call to Method

```
sales_attach = models.FileField("Attachment", upload_to=path_and_rename("complaint_files", 'sales'), max_length=500,
                                help_text="Browse a file")
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks.

Comment: I got error in project and uuid. so i have created my own function given as another answer

Answer (score 11):

if you want your function re-usable:

```
import hashlib
import datetime
import os
from functools import partial

def _update_filename(instance, filename, path):
    path = path

    filename = "..."

    return os.path.join(path, filename)

def upload_to(path):
    return partial(_update_filename, path=path)
```

You just have to use it this way:

```
document = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to("my/path"))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import random
import os
def generate_unique_name(path):
    def wrapper(instance, filename):
        extension = "." + filename.split('.')[-1]
        filename = str(random.randint(10,99)) + str(random.randint(10,99)) + str(random.randint(10,99)) + str(random.randint(10,99))  + extension
        return os.path.join(path, filename)
    return wrapper
```

#You just have to use it this way:#

```
 photo = models.FileField("Attachment", upload_to=generate_unique_name("pics"),max_length=500,help_text="Browse a photo")
```

Answer (score 3):

Incase this may help anyone.

```
import os
import uuid
import random

from datetime import datetime 

def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # Get Current Date
    todays_date = datetime.now()

    path = "uploads/{}/{}/{}/".format(todays_date.year, todays_date.month, todays_date.day)
    extension = "." + filename.split('.')[-1]
    stringId = str(uuid.uuid4())
    randInt = str(random.randint(10, 99))

    # Filename reformat
    filename_reformat = stringId + randInt + extension

    return os.path.join(path, filename_reformat)


class MyModel(models.Model):
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

Comment: or the path can be `path="uploads/"` for a single directory

Answer (score 1):

That much code is not needed you can just use single line code
fille._name=userid + transaction_uuid + file_extension

Like

```
class xyz(models.Model):
   file = models.FileField(upload_to="notice/")

   def add(request):
      file = request.POST['file']
      file._name = request.user.id + transaction_uuid +"."+ file._name.split('.')[1]
```

you can overwrite file name by overwriting _name value of file object.

Comment: Please Insert the code part as a code format and not as a text format

Answer (score 0):

*You can try this also work, name_of_submission is any column you want to attach the file*

```
import os

def update_filename(instance, filename):
    path = "upload/path/"
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    format = instance.name_of_submission +    str(instance.id_application) + "." + ext
    print(format)
    return os.path.join(path, format)
```

Answer (score -1):

The basic way is

```
import os

os.rename('a.txt', 'b.html')
```

For your situation, it would probably look like

```
os.rename ("a.txt", "{id}{uuid}.{ext}".format(id=userid, uuid=transaction_uuid, ext=file_extension))
```

Answer (score -1):

> Hi, i check all the answers, but someone are not updated, this is how
> in 2022 works whith clean code and following the [Django Documentation
> Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to), remember that you need to make a MIGRATION to make this work:
>
> ```
>  def AvatarSave(instance, filename):
>     #this line changes the name of the file to the user name and put the file extension at the end after the point
>     return 'users/avatars/{0}.{1}'.format(instance.id,filename.split('.')[-1])
>
>  avatar = models.ImageField(_("avatar"),upload_to=AvatarSave)
> ```

Comment: This is just a worse version of the accepted answer by @monkut. You even link to the same old version `3.2` of the Django docs. In contrast to yours, the accepted answer actually relates to the specifics of the OP with how their file should be named. You used some avatar example with an `ImageField` that has nothing to do with the OP.

Comment: sorry this work, for the latest version [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to), I do not remember why the other code not work for me

Comment: At the end i use this code, because i need the images whit the exact same name every time and i use other methods to make a cache of the images on my app, I am open to see comments about that:

```python
    def AvatarSave(instance, filename):
        file = 'users/avatars/{0}.{1}'.format(instance.id,
                                              filename.split('.')[-1])

        fullFile = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, file)
        if exists(fullFile):
            os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, fullFile))

        return file
```