# How can I rename the images uploaded in Django model

Tags: django, django-models

I have this code to submit the form:

```
form = form_class(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=object)
if form.is_valid(): 
form.save()
```

---

`image_path = models.ImageField(upload_to='books/')`

Currently  `books/book1/jpg` gets inserted into that field.

But I want that the image should be renamed to `modelName_pk`.jpg and that value gets saved in `image_path`

How can I achieve that?

Comment: This is a good question, idk why there are no answers.

Comment: The problem here is that before `save()` is called, pk is not assigned to the model instance. You can upload and then rename it by referring to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20139166/3803979

Answer (score 2):

Each of the uploaded files are saved to `request.FILES` which are instances of [UploadedFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile), so, using the name of the image field in the form you can access it: `request.FILES['imagename'].name`.

Then you can save the model instance as usual. Hope this helps someone else because this is a very old question