# Replacing a filefield in a form_clean function in django

Tags: django, django-forms

In my website, users are uploading audio files. I wish to convert all supported audio files to MP3.

I prefered to make the convertion in the filefield_clean function because in that moment I am also able to confirm that the file format uploaded is supported. In addition I am using S3 so it just before to file is uploaded to my S3 Storage.

My problem is how can I redirect the physical file used in the InMemoryUploadedFile ? I need to redirect it to my new converted file.

Is it possible to accomplish this in a clean operation ? If not, what is the best approch ?

Comment: Create a link to the mp3, but have a batch job asynchronously convert it. Don't do it on the fly in the FileField if you want to have some form of performance left in your application.

Comment: Audio files are very small so it isn't a big issue to convert it on the fly. Even that I am well aware of it. Still. cant figure out how to accomplish what I refered to.

Comment: What do you mean `redirect the physical file`? You mean how do you upload the .mp3 to S3?

Comment: I would like to my form will be pointing to the new converted mp3 file instead of the original uploaded files so when I save the form (It is a modalForm) the new file will gets uploaded instead of the original one.

Comment: Okay, here you go then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680391/in-django-changing-the-file-name-of-uploading-file