# Change the name of an uploaded file and save to folder in Django

Tags: python, django, file-handling

I have been trying this for the past day but still can't work on it.

Consider that the user uploads a `ReportCard` with

**models.py**

```
class ReportCard(models.Model):
  student_id = models.CharField(max_length=15)
  report_card = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I use `CharField` since it could be dynamic and so I store it this way.

So in my

**views.py**

```
  if report_card_form.is_valid():
    student_id = report_card_form.cleaned_data['id']
    report_card = request.FILES['report_card']
    report_card_form.save(student_id, report_card)
```

and of course, in my

**forms.py**

```
def save(student_id, report_card):
  count_report = ReportCard.objects.filter(student_id=student_id).count() + 1
  new_name = student_id + '_' + str(count_report+1)
  rc = ReportCard(student_id=student_id, report_card=new_name)
```

Each report card is saved in the folder that belongs to each student. Every student has his/her own folder.

My question is, how do I rename the report card file, and save it in the correct folder? I am not using `models` but I still think there is a possible way. Tried using `os` to rename the files but still to no avail. Any takers?

Comment: Are you trying to save the file? There's nothing in the code that does it.

Comment: Hi @RodXavier, I tried using the code that involves chunk but it is throwing me an error...takers?

Comment: Why aren't you using FileField ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In django changing the file name of uploading file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680391/in-django-changing-the-file-name-of-uploading-file)