# uploading file as id using models ind django

Tags: django, file-upload, django-models

I have short model definition

```
class File(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True);
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='%id')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True);
```

as u see (or not) I would like this model to handle upload so file name would be the same as row id. Is it possible to do it this way somehow?

Comment: Model itself will not upload anything for you, you still need the client side form to upload and a Django View to handle the request.

Comment: It is all done, but I am thinking if by changing upload_to I can achieve change in name of file into id. - I just put data from form to model as the easiest way.

Comment: So you have file = request.files['file'] and then file.filename into your char field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In django changing the file name of an uploaded file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680391/in-django-changing-the-file-name-of-an-uploaded-file)

Answer (score 1):

sure you can

```
def update_filename(instance, filename):
    filename_ = instance.id
    file_extension = filename.split('.')[-1]
    return '%s.%s' % (filename_, file_extension)

class File(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=update_filename)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

and I would change the class name to something else, so it does not shadow the built in `File`.

Comment: will id be known if I dont choose it before?

Comment: @oneat you dont need id field, why are you defining your own id?